# LocationManager.addProximityAlert(...) throws IllegalArgumentException("pending intent must be targeted to package")

Tags: android

I am trying to set up a geofence using `LocationManager.addProximityAlert(...)`, but I get an `IllegalArgumentException("pending intent must be targeted to package")`.

Here is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyIntentService.class);
intent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, radius, expiration, pendingIntent);
```

The first thing that LocationManager does is call `checkPendingIntent(intent)` which calls `intent.isTargetedToPackage()` which calls `ActivityManagerNative.isIntentSenderTargetedToPackage(IIntentSender sender)` https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/c80f952/core/java/android/app/ActivityManagerNative.java#4609

The result is `false` and I get an `IllegalArgumentException("pending intent must be targeted to package")`.

The same thing works fine if I use a `BroadcastReceiver` instead of an `IntentService`.

How do I fix this `IllegalArgumentException`?

P.S. I use `LocationManager` for devices which don't have Play Services installed. Using `IntentService` to immediately run some API requests, which may take some time. `IntentService` is registered in manifest as `<service android:name=".MyIntentService" android:exported="false"/>`.

**Update**: here's the code that works with BroadcastReceiver. AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="MyBroadcastReceiver.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

java code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("MyBroadcastReceiver.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION");
intent.setPackage(context.getPackageName());
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Can you post your manifest entry for the `BroadcastReceiver` that works

Comment: @Ge3ng see update in the post.

Comment: are both of these intents used? You may have a conflict of ids

Comment: No, only one of them is used at the same time.

Comment: Try changing the 0 in you PendingIntents to unique values.